# Parallelize python loop numpy.searchsorted using cython

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, parallel-processing, cython

I've coded a function using cython containing the following loop. Each row of array A1 is binary searched for all values in array A2. So each loop iteration returns a 2D array of index values. Arrays A1 and A2 enter as function arguments, properly typed.

The array C is pre-allocated at highest indent level as required in cython.

I simplified things a little for this question.

```
...
cdef np.ndarray[DTYPEint_t, ndim=3] C = np.zeros([N,M,M], dtype=DTYPEint)

for j in range(0,N):
    C[j,:,:]  = np.searchsorted(A1[j,:], A2, side='left' )
```

All's fine so far, things compile and run as expected. However, to gain even more speed I want to parallelize the j-loop. First attempt was simply writing

```
for j in prange(0,N, nogil=True):
    C[j,:,:]  = np.searchsorted(A1[j,:], A2, side='left' )
```

I tried many coding variations such as putting things in a separate nogil_function, assigning the result to an intermediate array and write a nested loop to avoid the assignment to the sliced part of C.

Errors usually are of the form "Accessing Python attribute not allowed without gil"

I can't get it to work. Any suggestions on how I can do this?

EDIT:

This is my setup.py

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup
    from setuptools import Extension
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup
    from distutils.extension import Extension


from Cython.Build import cythonize

import numpy

extensions = [Extension("matchOnDistanceVectors",
                    sources=["matchOnDistanceVectors.pyx"],
                    extra_compile_args=["/openmp", "/O2"],
                    extra_link_args=[]
                   )]


setup(
ext_modules = cythonize(extensions),
include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()]
)
```

I'm on windows 7 compiling with msvc. I did specify the /openmp flag, my arrays are of sizes 200*200. So everything seems in order...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that `searchsorted` releases the GIL itself (see https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/e2805398f9a63b825f4a2aab22e9f169ff65aae9/numpy/core/src/multiarray/item_selection.c, line 1664 "`NPY_BEGIN_THREADS_DEF`").

Therefore, you can do

```
for j in prange(0,N, nogil=True):
    with gil:
      C[j,:,:]  = np.searchsorted(A1[j,:], A2, side='left' )
```

That temporarily claims back the GIL to do the necessary work on Python objects (which is hopefully quick), and then it *should* be released again inside `searchsorted` allowing in the run largely in parallel.

---

To update I did a quick test of this (`A1.shape==(105,100)`, `A2.shape==(302,302)`, numbers are chosen pretty arbitrarily). For 10 repeats the serial version took 4.5 second, the parallel version took 1.4 seconds (test was run on a 4 core CPU). You don't get the 4x full speed-up, but you get close.

This was compiled as [described in the documentation](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/parallelism.html#compiling). I suspect if you aren't seeing speed-up then it could be any of: 1) your arrays are small enough that the function-call/numpy checking types and sizes overhead is dominating; 2) You aren't compiling it with OpenMP enabled; or 3) your compiler doesn't support OpenMP.

Comment: Yeah I tried that too, I saw an example somewhere on SO doing the same thing using np.cos() I think. Things will compile that way, but there doesn't seem to be actual multithreading going on. But I'd be happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: I haven't tested it (and can't easily right now) but my reading of the `searchsorted` code was that it should probably work. Just to check the obvious, you have made sure it's compiled with the openmp options on in setup.py?

Comment: I'm using gcc and linux I'm afraid so I can't really do much except say "yes, it looks like it's probably right..."

Answer (score 0):

You have a bit of a catch 22. You need the GIL to call `numpy.searchsorted` but the GIL prevents any kind of parallel processing. Your best bet is to write your own `nogil` version of `searchsorted`:

```
cdef mySearchSorted(double[:] array, double target) nogil:
    # binary search implementation

for j in prange(0,N, nogil=True):
    for k in range(A2.shape[0]):
        for L in range(A2.shape[1]):
            C[j, k, L]  = mySearchSorted(A1[j, :], A2[k, L])
```

`numpy.searchsorted` also has a non trivial amount of overhead, so if N is large it makes sense to use your own `searchsorted` just to reduce the overhead.

Comment: Wouldn't such an approach give a lot of overhead from calling mySearchSorted() many many times? I suppose if I'd write my own sort function, I'd directly code it in C/C++ and interface with that code using cython.

Comment: functions defined using `cdef` are translated directly into c functions by python and can only be called from cython code. `cdef` and `cpdef` functions, in general, have performance similar to c code. Functions imported from python modules or defined using `def` have more overhead. `searchsorted` specifically has a lot of overhead associated with numpy type and correctness checking. You can do any necessary checking once, instead of every time `searchsorted` is called.